# AWS EBS drive needs to be reduced in size

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a 1TB AWS EBN drive which is around 25% full. So I'm wasting money on storage.

Is there any way to make a smaller snapshot of this drive? I have a Drupal website running off it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, it is not safe to reduce the size of a server in such a fashion. Other providers like Digital Ocean and Rackspace also don't allow for it.

What you can do is to create a whole new server from scratch and copy all the data from the existing server to the new one. There are tutorials that you can find easily by a simple google search but I wouldn't recommend them (they themselves don't)

Answer (score 0):

These steps are tested in Amazon, CentOS, Red Hat.

**Part 1 : Preparation Phase**

```
1. Stop the instance and create snapshot of the volume.
2. Now launch a temp working instance.
3. Create a new "source" volume from the snapshot created in step 1 and attach it to the temp working instance as /dev/sdm.
4. Create a new "destination" volume and attach it to the temp working instance as /dev/sdo.
```

**Part 2 : Conversion**

```
1. Partition the 'destination' volume.
parted /dev/xvdo --script 'mklabel msdos mkpart primary 1M -1s print quit'
partprobe /dev/xvdo
udevadm settle

2. Check the 'source' volume and minimize the size of original filesystem to speed up the process. We do not want to copy free disk space in the next step.
e2fsck -f /dev/xvdm
resize2fs -M /dev/xvdm
- Output from resize command:
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/xvdm to 269020 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/xvdm is now 269020 blocks long.

3. Duplicate 'source' to 'destination' volume.
dd if=/dev/xvdm of=/dev/xvdo1 bs=4K count=269020
***NB: Ensure you use the exact value for "bs=" and "count=" from the resize2fs command***

4. Resize the filesystem on the 'destination' volume after the transfer completed.
resize2fs /dev/xvdo1
```

**Part 3: Finalize**

```
1. Create a snapshot of the 'destination' volume.
2. Now create EBS volume from the same and attach it to original instance and mount the volume.
```

Taken the reference from the below [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=155526)